# Recognizing comments with no specific ending on JLex

Tags: comments, lex

I have to recognize comments like this using JLex:

```
;this is a comment
```

as you can see, it has no recognizable ending. I've searched everywhere, and according to what I found I should use something like one of these:

```
COMMENT = [;]([^\n])*
COMMENT = [;]([^\r\n])*
```

But then when a normal word comes after the comment (in the next line) I get an error. My parser is just fine, I'm sure my problem is on my JLex. Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you post more information about the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try entering a new state when the comment begins, and leaving that state when it ends.

Here's an example from JLexPHP.

```
<?php
include 'jlex.php';
%%
%state COMMENTS
%%

<YYINITIAL> ";" {
    $this->yybegin(self::COMMENTS);
}
<COMMENTS> [^\n] {
    return $this->createToken();
}
<COMMENTS> [\n] {
    $this->yybegin(self::YYINITIAL);
}
```